# Can't install a removed app

Tags: macos, applications

I installed an app named 'dayone' from App Store earlier, and then I was told that my OS(version 10.11.6) was not compatible with the current app version. So firstly I removed the target app, hoping to re-install that app later after upgrading the OS, and then did the upgrade(version 10.14.2)

However, after I upgraded the OS, I found that the app is still in the **Updates** list of the App Store panel. Clicking the UPDATE button won't install the app or update the app(there's nothing to update anyway since I had already removed it)

I suspect that the app was not deleted completely in the first removal, but I can't find anything about the app left in my mac.
Also it could be an OS bug?

Could anyone please help?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How did you remove the app?  Does the app show up in Finder under 'Applications'?

Comment: @fsb in the Launchpad, I kept pressing the option key so that all the app icons were 'shaking'  and deletable, and it is from there I deleted the app.

Comment: @fsb no, the app doesn't show up in the Finder under 'Applications' any more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you installed Day One v2.  [According to Day One](http://help.dayoneapp.com/troubleshooting/uninstalling-and-reinstalling-day-one-20-for-macos), there's a specific way to uninstall the application.  I think you just need to delete the folder indicated in #2.

> 1. Quit Day One Mac.
> 2. Paste this into the **Go to Folder** window in Finder: `~/Library/Group Containers/5U8NS4GX82.dayoneapp2/`.
> 3. Drag the entire folder to your Mac Desktop. (This contains a local copy of your journal data backups and might be useful if any problems arise when you reinstall and reimport your data into Day One Mac 2.0.).
> 4. Drag the Day One Mac 2.0 app from the Applications folder to the Trash Can.
> 5. Be sure to quit Day One Helper in the menu bar if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Before I asked the question here, I had already tried searching anything related to 'dayone' in the finder, and deleted everything that has 'dayone' in it. So I think I had already deleted the folder in the #2 as it is obviously not there now...

Comment: Did you have v2 or Claasic installed?

Comment: Actually, I installed the default version the App Store provides, which is 2.9.2.
But after the installation, it reminded me that it was not compatible with my then OS version, and I was recommended to install a previous version(classic?) of the app, which I did(through the interface of the app itself).

Comment: But this classic version only showed me a lock interface asking me to input the password, I inputed my password of dayone account, but nothing happened, and only got the "Hint: F num" words below the password input field. Then I deleted them all. And start to upgrade my macOS version to be the latest. After I finished it, I am beginning to have the current problem...

Comment: So it appears you have the Classic version installed now.  Did you look at the Day One site for uninstalling that version?  The steps are different than what's in my answer.

Comment: I'm happy the problem has been resolved!  In order to help others, it would be great if you could post an answer with that info.

Comment: actually I don’t know what was the reason, I did what you told me to do, and a few other tweaks, none of them worked, so I left it there, and a fewer hours later, the app was downloadable... ;-p